# How can I use an array to create new objects without calling them immediately?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am new to programming and i am working on a small quiz game. I am using an Constructor to create an object to represent a question blueprint. I want the object to hold the 'solution' and 'possible answers' to a question. The possible answers I am keeping in a array of objects. The array is holding all the new objects, and works great when tested in the console. (But doesn't work properly when script is run).

So the issue is that, in my array, I create a new object but it is called to the console immediately. I don't want the array to automatically print to the console. Because I need this for a game, I want to only print the question by index requested. But it is printing the entire array to the console without being called.

(This might have to do with execution stack some how, but I need help figuring this out. I am very new to programming, so please be detailed).

```
var questionList = [
new Question('is learning hard?', ['yes', 'no'], 'no'),
new Question('Is JavaScript a fun programming language?', ['yes','no'], 'yes'),];

var pickQuestion = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
console.log(questionList[pickQuestion].ask);


//Question class (below):

var Question = function(question, answers, correct_answer) {
  this.question = question;
  this.answers = answers;
  this.correct_answer = correct_answer;
  ask: {
    console.log(this.question);
    for(var i = 0; i < answers.length; i++){
      console.log(i + ": " + answers[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is printing that should not be printing?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "calling the objects", nor why selecting a single element in your `questions` array would "print the entire array to console". If you're executing all your code in the browser console, especially line-by-line, it will return the result of your code, regardless of whether you explicitly `console.log()`. I'm not sure if this is the source of confusion but perhaps it's related.

Comment: The Question constructor just sets the arguments, and has a function inside that traverses that data. So, for example if I had Question(name) it sets it like this.name = name; And the for-loop is just traversing the array as usual, nothing special.

Comment: @learnbasic It seems that sharing the `Question` class would really help here.

Comment: None of that involves `console.log`.  What is printing that is not supposed to be printing?

Comment: @Taplar I just want it to print questions[pickQuestion] to the console. When I run the script from html it prints the entire array to the console. I dont know why this is happening, and dont want it to do that. Hope that clears things up!

Comment: if `questions` is an array, and `pickQuestions` is an index, then syntatically it would not be the case that you log the entire array.  You appear to be seeing something that we are not seeing from the code you have provided.  Please provide an [mcve] of the issue

Comment: Iv added the questions constructor, hope that is useful.

Comment: Your constructor has multiple `console.log()`s in it that will fire every time you do `new Question(...)`. Not only does it immediately log the question, but it also logs every possible answer. Is `ask` supposed to be a *function*?

Comment: It seems you are defining the ask function improperly. Try `this.ask = function() { ...`

Comment: If this is verbatim your code, all your Questions are being given the same inputs as well.

Comment: AFOC submitted that I was not defining the ask as a function. So once I changed ask: {  to ask: () => {   it accessed it by index perfectly. Unfortunately, now I cant call it using the line: console.log(questionList[pickQuestion].ask()); because its not considered a function for some reason.

Comment: Thanks for help everyone, AFOC solved my issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the `ask` property is not correctly defined as a function.

```
var Question = function(question, answers, correct_answer) {
  this.question = question;
  this.answers = answers;
  this.correct_answer = correct_answer;
  this.ask = () => {    // note the brackets & arrow, could also be function()
    console.log(this.question);
    for(var i = 0; i < answers.length; i++){
      console.log(i + ": " + answers[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh Thanks that fixed the first part of it, but introduced a new error. Now When I use console.log(questionList[pickQuestion].ask()); it says that it isn't a function, when it is.

Comment: Also you can just do `questionList[pickQuestion].ask()`. Since there are log statements in that function, the enclosing console.log is redundant.

Comment: Oh man, thanks so much! It works like a charm now. I originally thought that when using function constructors I could make a function by simply doing ( functionName : {} ). My mistake it seems.

Comment: Also thanks for the info about the console.log being redundant. Appreciate it.

Comment: You can define functions like that if you use the class syntax & explicitly set a constructor: 
`class Question {
constructor(question, answers, correct_answer){
  this.question = question;
  this.answers = answers;
  this.correct_answer = correct_answer;
}
  ask() {    
    console.log(this.question);
    for(var i = 0; i < this.answers.length; i++){
      console.log(i + ": " + this.answers[i]);
    }
  }
}`

Answer (score 0):

Your class definition needs some work. To add a method, **the standard way is to add it to the constructor's [prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes)** like `Question.prototype.ask = function() {...}` or to define it as a method using the new JS [`class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/class) syntax (this still adds it to the prototype). Otherwise, if you create a new function inside the constructor, you will make a new function for every single `Question`. This will work, but it isn't a good practice (in most cases) since you only need a single function. The following snippets should work mostly as expected and would be better options than setting the function inside the constructor:

"Old" JS (Using `prototype`):

```js
function Question(question, correctAnswer, answers) {
  this.question = question;
  this.answers = answers;
  this.correctAnswer = correctAnswer;
}
Question.prototype.ask = function() {
  console.log(this.question);
  for (let i = 0; i < this.answers.length; i++) {
    console.log(i + ": " + this.answers[i]);
  }
};

function pickQuestion(q) {
  return q[
    Math.floor(Math.random() * q.length)
  ];
}

var question = pickQuestion([
  new Question('Choose Answer 1', 1, [
    'Answer 1',
    'Answer 2',
    'Answer 3'
  ]),
  new Question('Choose Answer 3', 3, [
    'Answer 1',
    'Answer 2',
    'Answer 3',
  ]),
  new Question('Choose Answer 2', 2, [
    'Answer 1',
    'Answer 2',
    'Answer 3',
  ])
]);

question.ask();
```

"New" JS (using `class` and other features):

```js
class Question {
  constructor(question, correctAnswer, answers) {
    this.question = question
    this.answers = answers
    this.correctAnswer = correctAnswer
  }

  ask() {
    console.log(this.question)
    for (let i = 0; i < this.answers.length; i++) {
      console.log(i + ": " + this.answers[i])
    }
  }
}

const pickQuestion = q => q[
  Math.floor(Math.random() * q.length)
]

const question = pickQuestion([
  new Question('Choose Answer 1', 1, [
    'Answer 1',
    'Answer 2',
    'Answer 3'
  ]),
  new Question('Choose Answer 3', 3, [
    'Answer 1',
    'Answer 2',
    'Answer 3',
  ]),
  new Question('Choose Answer 2', 2, [
    'Answer 1',
    'Answer 2',
    'Answer 3',
  ]),
])

question.ask()
```

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed response, and even going as far as providing 2 sets of solutions. I will give this a try in a little while, thanks in advance!

Comment: Here's hoping it helps out!